# Align horinzontal components in pull-right panel Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying align horizontal components in pull-right panel, but it's stays in vertical align.

Follow I'm doing:

```
        <div class="pull-right">

              <select class="form-control" id="month" onChange="selectMonth()">
                 <option value="01">
                    Mês
                 </option>
                 <option value="01">
                    Janeiro
                 </option>
                 <option value="02">
                    Fevereiro
                 </option>
                 <option value="03">
                    Março
                 </option>
                 <option value="04">
                    Abril
                 </option>
              </select>

              <select class="form-control" id="day" onChange="selectDay()">
                 <option value="01">
                    Dia
                 </option>
                 <option value="02">
                    01
                 </option>
                 <option value="03">
                    07
                 </option>
                 <option value="04">
                    14
                 </option>
              </select>

        </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/lbclucascosta/e30toqa1/2/

This is caused by `form-control`, but all I tried to do don't works. I want do leave the month select and day select side by side. How I can to do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add class `form-inline` to your `div`

updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/e30toqa1/3/

```
<div class="pull-right form-inline"></div>
```

and bootstrap reference: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-inline